# window.resize event only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, jquery-events

I am trying to execute things on `window.resize`, but I can't even get alert to work more than once. All of the code I have is this:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>//I have this library in this html's file directory
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      window.resize(alert("yolo"));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

I have also tried several variations:

```
window.resize(...)

window.on("resize",...)

window.one("resize",...)

$(window).resize(...)

$(window).on("resize",...)

$(window).one("resize",...)
```

None of them work. Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Comment: Not sure why it does not work. Worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bakgq9g7/

Comment: in pure JS it's `window.onresize = resizeHandler;`

Comment: well with just `window` you wouldnt be able to call `.resize`, `on`, or `one` as its not a jQuery object, and for the jQuery calls it expects a function reference not the return of a function call, and in the case of the return of a alert call its `undefined` so you arent setting a callback at all

Comment: A duplicate, a duplicate.. basically a function is *not* supplied as the event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only gets called once since the document.ready is consumed on the page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     window.resize(alert("yolo"));
});
```

You would need to attach an event handler to the window
`window.onresize = function() { alert("yolo"); };`
or

`$(window).resize(function () {alert("yolo");});`

Comment: also, probably smarter to use `console.log` instead of `alert()` if you don't want to go crazy from the popups

Comment: You still have it as `$(document).ready(function(){
      window.resize(alert("yolo"));
    });`. You want `window.resize(function () {alert("yolo");});`

Comment: You are binding the function to the page load event, not the window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert('yolo')` is getting executed at the moment it's consumed by the javascript runtime. That's why you're seeing it only once, when the page loads.

Also `window.resize` doesn't exist but `window.onresize` does :

```
window.onresize = function (){
    alert('yolo');
};
```

Comment: `.resize()` exists in jQuery, which is what he is using.

Comment: `window.resize()` doesn't exist, jQuery or not.

`$(window).resize()` does, in jQuery only.